# If Improper Integral Converges, Does Integrand Converge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

If we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) dt$$ converges, does this imply that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}f(t) = 0?$$ If so, how to prove?

The Laplace transform for a function $f(t)$ is
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)\ dt.$$
in some derivations the author simply states that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \left(e^{-st}f(t)\right) = 0,$$
but I wasn't sure this is universally true.

Comment: No, however, if $\lim_{t\to \infty }f(t)$ exist, then it converges to $0$.

Comment: @SineoftheTime No, by Surb's comment

Comment: @SineoftheTime - Just put a small bump at each integer, each one unit high, but with bases that get very narrow very quickly. Of course, as mentioned, the limit doesn't exist, as opposed to existing and not equalling zero.

Comment: (I said 'no' because I thought you meant $\lim_x f(x)$ exists but doesn't equal zero)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, in general. Consider for instance the function: $$(0,\infty)\ni x\mapsto\begin{cases}n&x\in[n,n+1/n^3],n\in\Bbb N\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$Its Riemann integral is easily seen to be: $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{n}{n^3}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$But this function doesn't converge. It is possible to make a continuous version of the same counterexample, so continuity is not relevant.

If the integrand converges we can prove the limit is necessarily zero:

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be Riemann integrable on every compact interval and have a limit in $\overline{\Bbb R}$ as $x\to\infty$, call it $M$, and suppose: $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t f$$Exists in $\Bbb R$. It is clear that if $M=\pm\infty$, for large $K$ and all large $t$ we get $|f|>K$ on $(t,\infty)$ *and* that $f$ is eventually of constant sign, so that for all $h>0$: $$\left|\int_t^{t+h}f\right|=\int_t^{t+h}|f|>Kh\overset{h\to\infty}\to\infty$$Thus $f$ is *not* improperly integrable, a contradiction. This case never happens, so suppose $M$ is finite now.
>
> For any prescribed $\epsilon>0$ and some large $T$, $|f-M|<\epsilon$ on $(T,\infty)$. Thus: $$-\epsilon-\int_t^{t+1}f<M<\epsilon+\int_t^{t+1}f$$When $t>T$. Furthermore, there is $T'>T$ such that $\left|\int_{t}^{t+1}f\right|<\epsilon$ for $t>T'$ (since a convergent improper integral must also have an associated Cauchy sequence) so: $$-2\epsilon<M<2\epsilon$$When $t>T'$. This is not dependent on $t,T,T'$ though, and $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary. $M=0$ is forced.